# How to do following mask input problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i am having a script to mask a textbox,here it it

```
<script src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/
files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

      $('#j').mask('99:99');
         });
</script>
```

i am also having a script to dynamically add text box while i click a button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

                var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

                for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                        case "text":
                                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                                newcell.childNodes[0].id="j";
                                alert(newcell.childNodes[0].id);
                                break;
                        case "checkbox":
                                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                                break;
                        case "select-one":
                                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                                break;
                    }
                }
            }

            function deleteRow(tableID) {
                try {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if(null != chkbox &amp;&amp; true == chkbox.checked) {
                        if(rowCount <= 1) {
                            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                            break;
                        }
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                    }


                }
                }catch(e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
    </script>
```

and my input box are

```
<INPUT type="text" name="STime[]" id="j"/>
```

```
<INPUT type="text" name="ETime[]" id="j"/>
```

the problem i am facing now is, the first text box will have a masked structure,but after i add a text box dynamically with help of j script, i will not get the text box as masked?why?? what i did wrong?

Comment: Just of Note the id attribute of your HTML elements should be unique.  you should never have two input elements with the same Id.  Use Class instead and assign a common classname.

Comment: I dont understand that?? can u gave me a sample??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [livequery plug-in](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs).
Then give all elements you want to mask the class `maskme`. Now you can do:

```
$(".maskme").livequery(function(){
    $(this).mask('99:99');
});
```

This will mask inputs added even after the code is first run.

Comment: I was scratching my head with the .live() function, thinking that there wasn't an appropriate event for this.  Thanks for posting, I learned somethin' :)

Comment: Hey,its working on the first text boxes,but it not working on the dynamic generated textbox.

Comment: @Alex - Should work. Do the dynamically added text elements also have `class="maskme" ?

Comment: yes i do that....but not working.....newcell.childNodes[0].class="j";  name="ETime[]" class="j"

Comment: @Alex - Try running jQuery.livequery.registerPlugin("addRow") before the code I posted. The only other suggestion I have if that doesn't work is to switch to using jQuery to add the new input elements instead of pure javascript.

Comment: @Adam  Livequery is not necessary look at my answer

Answer (score 19):

Create an event binding to an input with the class (don't use ID if you don't have to) you are targeting. Use the jQuery .on method http://api.jquery.com/on/

Example:

```
<input class="classSelector" />

<script>  
  $(document).on("focus", "classSelector", function() { 
    $(this).mask("99:99");
  });
</script>
```

You can dynamically create as many of those inputs you want and mask them using the on event binding. Every new input with that class you create will get that event handler attached to it.

Answer (score 3):

First Dont use ID on the input

```
<input type="text" name="STime[]" class="jClass"/>
```

Second if your using jQuery then use it.  This is much easier to read.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {
      var table = $("#" + tableID); //get the table
      var firstRowClone = $("tr:first", table).clone(); //clone the first row
      $("input:checkbox",firstRowClone).attr("checked", false);  // set all checkboxes to unchecked
      $("select", firstRowClone).each(function () { //Set all select lists to select first item
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
      }
      table.append(firstRowClone); //append the cloned row to the table.
      $("input:text", firstRowClone).val("").mask("99:99"); //set all input type="text" with value of "" and sets the mask on the clone.

    });

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
      $("#" + tableId + " tr:not(:eq(0))").remove(); //Remove all rows except the first row.         
    }


    $(document).ready(function {
      $('.jClass').mask('99:99'); //sets the mask on any rows loaded initially
    });

</script>
```

Comment: True, assuming that addRow is the only place that adds new text elements that need to be masked, which it probably is. Very good suggestion.

Comment: @alex ... I edited the code above....the difference is apply the mask after you append the cloned row to the DOM.  But it would really be helpful if you said what is not working. The statement "it not working" is not helpful at all.  Please give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The mask plug-in is not binding live to new elements in the DOM, but rather is binding on the then-existing element from your $('#j') selector.

1. Use a class instead of an ID (since you cannot legally have two elements with the same id on the page), and
2. If necessary, re-call `.mask()` on your dynamically-created elements after adding to the DOM.

Comment: I dont understand that?? can u gave me a sample??

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Id use class in script  for multipal use time mask in php
  ghj

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.